# Jquery: Passing a parameter into the function in .click()

Tags: jquery

```
function AAA(i){console.log(i);}

$('div').click({i:'clicked'},AAA);
```

How do I pass a parameter/data into the function when using .click()? the above does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data passed in is available as `event.data` inside the event handlers callback function

```
function AAA(event){
    console.log( event.data.i );
}

$('div').click({i:'clicked'},  AAA);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/y89x7/)

Comment: Can you give me some scenarios where we can pass `eventData` in click handler? I have not seen/used this before :)

Answer (score 1):

An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.

```
function AAA(event){
     console.log(event.data.i);
}


$('div').click({i:'clicked'},AAA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function(){
           AAA('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this

```
$('div').on('click', AA('test'));
```